# IBM datastage 8.7 script to remove special characters oracle 11g

Tags: etl, datastage

I am wondering if I need to implement a solution at Datastage end and/or Oracle 11g DB end to fix the issue of existence of non-ascii characters in the descriptions. Because the databases are using different character sets, the conversion of one set to another occasionally convert a single non-ascii character into multiple characters causing a truncation error.

Sample description 
": ¿What date did this happen?¿ xxxxx: ¿Wednesday, so it would have been ..... "
":had to go to the doctor yesterday.¿ xxxxxx: ¿I¿ll just get you to state your"

Ideally (for longer term) I would like to replace with the corresponding character, i.e. some extended quotes should become a regular quote.

For short term i have a sample script written which basically replaces all special characters with a space -

```
UPDATE rcmain.rc_description
SET    desc_description  = REPLACE(desc_description, CHR(191), ' ')
WHERE  desc_description LIKE '%' || CHR(191) || '%'
```

From the above script I was to create a DataStage "ctlCleanseSourceFile" job that calls a UNIX shell script "Replace_extended_characters.sh" to strip the special characters out of the XML files.

This could be done once the XML file are merged into a single file.

Modify one of the attached sample files to create the shell script.

It should:Use the sed statement in the samples, Store a backup of the original file before the replacement. Save this to the same archive directory as the other files for the run & report on the characters replaced if possible.

Is there a better way to handle this situation and not use space to description field.

"Apologies for the long post"

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, this is a quick response;

What are your NLS settings?

I had an issue like yourself reading XML and changing the source stage NLS to windows 1252 resolved the 'invalid character' issue I was having (source of the files was a windows server but Datastage was on Unix so using UTF-8)

Comment: Thanks for the reply back and advise, will try to change the settings to windows 1252 and see if that works any of its charms.

Comment: Hi Dan, Can you advise if the changes made to the underlying DB will that affect the data straightaway or will I need to reload the data all over again to get it processed by new Settings ?

Comment: Abby, I didn't need to make changes to the DB just the source node within Datastage, changing the NLS settings on that meant that it read the XML correctly for me. Would you be able to advise what the source node is (oracle connector perhaps?)

Comment: Hi Dan,
When we read our XML file and then keep a track on the data that is being passed through all stages of STAGING through to PRESENTATION we do see correct interpretation of data. No funny characters replaced.
However, from presentation to the DB is where the issue lies. So I am thinking to run a unix script to replace all funny characters with a < Space > ... cant see to have any other option. your thoughts ?

Comment: Abby, Why not a transformer stage before the delivery node to replace these inconsistent characters (as its then contained within the job and no external scripts are required). I'd be interested to know what the delivery node is as it may be the load utility is trying to convert the data on pass through.